# How to give the multiple values in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am a noob when it comes to SQL syntax. And I am using PHP

I have a table with lots of rows and columns of course. Let say look like this

```
       name  token       ids
----------------------------
ROW1 | abc   sometoken   12
ROW2 | xyz   sometoken1  13
ROW3 | abc   sometoken   15
ROW4 | abc   sometoken   16
```

From the above table, I am trying to get the data by name and id by this query

```
select name,id from table where name='$name','$id';
```

By this query, I am trying to restrict the user from adding the same id with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Mysql [Logical Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html)

> You can use `AND` or `OR` Operator with your query to add multiple
>   where clause.

if you want to check same name with same id you should try as below.

```
select name,id from table where name='$name' AND id = '$id';
```

Comment: Upvote for the link. Answers need explanations and reference (optional) as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 123 IN(name, id);

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` Operator: It should work.

```
SELECT name,id FROM table WHERE name='$name' AND id = '$id';
```